# Reply to a message with a webhook

Tags: discord.py

I have this code to send a message by a webhook. I want to reply to the same message, but it's not working as expected. Is there any way to add a reply message through webhook to the same message sent before by webhook?

```
webhook = await channel.create_webhook(name=message.author.name)
msg = await webhook.send(content = str(result.text))
await msg.reply('TEST')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the actual message when sending it with a webhook you need to add the `wait=True` keyword argument.

```py
webhook = await channel.create_webhook(name=message.author.name)
msg = await webhook.send(content=str(result.text), wait=True)
await msg.reply('TEST')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, is there a way to reply from a webhook too instead of bot instance?

Comment: webhooks can't reply at all

Answer (score 2):

As of today, replying to messages using webhooks is not possible.

https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2251

I doubt it'll never be implemented, see my comment

https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/discussions/3282#discussioncomment-1691383